# Can't connect to websockets URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, web-sockets

In all my browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) I am getting an error about not being able to establish a connection to the server at wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/.

I have disabled all plugins, cleared cache, and checked on a different internet connection. It's only started happening in the last hour or so.

I first noticed the problem on https://english.stackexchange.com/election, because it was causing the CSS to render incorrectly, but I'm getting the same message on other sites as well.

[image: example of CSS failing to render]

Comment: The CSS issue has nothing to do with websockets. I have pinged the designers to look at it. As for websockets - what error are you getting? Is this still happening?

Comment: @Oded great, seems that the CSS problem is now fixed. I did a bit more digging and it seems that the `HTTPS Everywhere` plugin was causing the issue. The error I get is `The connection to wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted while the page was loading.` I had set HTTPS Everywhere not to run on the current page, but it seems that I had to disable it entirely and restart Firefox to prevent it from causing the error.

Comment: OK - glad to hear things have been resolved :)